# karate-netty memory leaks with 0.9.6

Tags: mocking, netty, karate

I realize karate 0.9.6 is a pretty old version at this point (nashorn and everything), but I'm not clear on how used karate-netty is for any version. We're finding that under moderate load, karate-netty really likes to leak memory. As we're running load tests on a service that connects to a mock powered by karate-netty, we're finding the load test is actually blocked by karate-netty falling over and needing to be respawned, with error responses flowing out in the mean time, which is obviously a problem. We've tried scaling the instance up, but we can't put enough instances to keep up with the traffic. I think we went up to 16 instances last time and still had significant errors from karate-netty falling over due to OOM errors.

I saw that karate-netty underwent a pretty substantial reworking in 1.1.0. My questions is: are the maintainers of Karate aware of any such memory issue (either in 0.9.6 or a more recent version?) And if they are, is there some magic version which is known to solve or mitigate the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This has never been reported. And we certainly don't work on old versions.

Comment: Gotcha. Are there any upgrade guides available for karate-netty?

Comment: @skibrianski nothing other than https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

Comment: Right. 1.0 isn't a good option for us since multi mock is not supported, so I guess we'd be looking at a 0.9.6 -> 1.1 upgrade and there appears to be some differences related to classpath handling there. Thanks anyhow, we'll figure it out!